# Get-Child item is moving System32 Files when not called

Tags: powershell, move, get-childitem

I have a script running quite often throughout a working day. As of lately it moved what appears to be all of my System32 file. I know the System32 files are running through the script as they are being organized and mapped 'correctly'.

However, I am never calling the system32 directory nor am I calling anything on the C drive. Why would the script turn to the directory that isnt being called or even a different drive path for that matter?

Since then has happen I have added a -Include *.pdf* so that it will only move. This change is bolded and italicized below . This should work correctly even if system32 is somehow directed again, correct?

```
##Hashtables

 

$srcRoot = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Groups\Anoka\10thDistrict\eSignature and Workflow\Unsigned\*\*\Signed - Return to Court Admin' -Directory).FullName

$dstRoot = "D:\Groups\Anoka\10thDistrict\eSignature and Workflow\Signed"

 

# map is defined

$map = @{

    '02' = '02 Anoka Court Admin Signed'

    '13' = 'PICK Court Admin Signed'

    '30' = 'PICK Court Admin Signed'

    '33' = 'PICK Court Admin Signed'

    '58' = 'PICK Court Admin Signed'

    '71' = '71 Sherburne Court Admin Signed'

    '82' = '82 Washington Court Admin Signed'

    '86' = '86 Wright Court Admin Signed'

    'CS' = 'Centralized Support Unit Signed'

}

 

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -File ***-Include *pdf**** -Force -Recurse) {

    $key = $file.BaseName.Substring(0,2)

    if ($map.ContainsKey($key)) {

        $fileName = $file.Name

        $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath $map[$key]

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir)) {

            # Create destination directory below if needed for duplicates

        }

        if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName)) {

            # Error message if file already exists at destination

            Write-Error -Message "File $fileName already exists at $dstDir"

            # go next here

            continue

        }

        # OK to move file

        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dstDir

        # go next here

        continue

    }

 

    # this is else for -not Contains()

    $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath 'District Wide Signed - Error Naming Convention'

    # should test if `Errors` folder exists, but should exist

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir)) {

        # Create destination directory below if needed for Errors

    }

    if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName)) {

        # throw error here and if needed

        # go next after error

        continue

    }

    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dstDir

}
```

Comment: did you take into account what was suggested in your previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199023/get-child-item-move-is-moving-system32-files)? On another note, `Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -File ***-Include *pdf****`, is this your actual code or has it been sanitized to be posted here? You should get an error or 2. Should look like this: `Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -Filter *pdf* -File`

Answer (score 2):

[Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) gave the crucial pointer in a comment:

- Surprisingly, when you pass `$null` or `''` (the empty string) to the (potentially positionally implied) `-Path` parameter of the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet, it quietly targets the *current* location (directory) -  see [GitHub issue #17793](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17793)
- By contrast, the `-LiteralPath` parameter reports an *error* if you try to pass `$null` or `''`

You can infer the following from that with respect to your problem:

- `$srcRoot` is `$null`

  - This in turn implies that your wildcard pattern `D:\Groups\Anoka\10thDistrict\eSignature and Workflow\Unsigned\*\*\Signed - Return to Court Admin` matches no existing directory.
- The current location (directory) when your script runs happens to be `C:\Windows\System32`.

The immediate fix is to test `$srcRoot` immediately after assignment and abort the script if it is `$null`, i.e. if the source directory cannot be found:

```bash
$srcRootPattern = 'D:\Groups\Anoka\10thDistrict\eSignature and Workflow\Unsigned\*\*\Signed - Return to Court Admin'

$srcRoot = (Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRootPattern -Directory).FullName

if (-not $srcRoot) { throw "No directory matching '$srcRootPattern' found." }
```

---

As for using `-Include *.pdf`: it limits `Get-ChildItem`'s output to files with a `.pdf` extension, so in that sense it would *lessen* your problem in that the wrongly targeted `C:\Windows\System32` directory subtree probably contains *no* such files, which means that no move operations will be attempted.

Of course, it doesn't *fix* your problem, which requires ensuring that the correct source directory is identified and targeted.

Comment: Thank you both. I do believe this is what happened. However, this is running as a scheduled task and i'm not actively watching the script run and can terminate it if I throw an error. What would be an efficient way to verify that the $srcRoot exists before running? I would think it would be needed within the loop to consistently verify the $srcRoot existence. Could I use Set-Location -Path Filesystem:: here?

Comment: @MediumRare, the test for whether a directory matches is already in the answer; you can simply negate the test and use it to enclose the rest of your script (or use the test as-is and replace `throw` with `exit`): `if ($srcRoot) { .. . }`. `Set-Location` would only work if only ever at most _one_ existing directory matches the pattern.